# Character Test Function inside Ternary Operator

Tags: c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm very new to C and programming.

I came across the sample coding for Character Testing Function used in the following if statement.

```
> for(i=0; i<strlen(password); i++)
{
    if(isdigit(password[i]))
    {
        hasDigit = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if(isupper(password[i]))
    {
        hasUpper = 1;
        continue;
    }
    if(islower(password[i]))
    {
        hasLower = 1;
}

if ((hasDigit) && (hasUpper) && (hasLower))
    {
        printf("\n Well done, %s\n", user);
        printf("Your password is successfully created with an upper and a lowercase");
        printf(" letters and number(s).\n");
    }else
    {
        printf("\n\n You should consider a new password, %s\n", user);
        printf("One that uses upper and lowercase letters");
        printf(" and a number.\n");
    }
```

Then I want to use Ternary Operator to simplify it, so I did the following inside the for-loop.

```
    hasDigit = isdigit(password[i])? 1:0;
    continue;

    hasUpper = isupper(password[i])? 1:0;
    continue;

    hasLower = islower(password[i])? 1:0;
```

The results are different.  I'd like to know how could I correct it or if I can use the Ternary Operator in this case at all?

Comment: Ask yourself what will happen when the loop finds a digit as the first character, but not in other positions. It will undo the flag that was set. You should not set it to `0`, because you already found a digit.

Comment: You're always `continue`ing whether the character is a digit in the 2nd version

Comment: As for ternary: `hasDigit = isdigit(password[i])? 1:0;` is pretty much the same effect as `hasDigit = isdigit(password[i]);`

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's pointlessly obtuse. `hasDigit = isdigit() ? 1 : hasDigit;`. But that forcing of users to use those characters is mightily dumb in the first place. You will accept a password like `Trump2020`, which is yes, very hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

The original code performs **set** operations on the flags but it never do any **clear** operations.

The ternary implementation will **also do clear**. Consequently it doesn't do the same as the original code. Further, in your code the `continue` is done unconditionally which also will change the final result (in most cases).

In other words: The function of your implementation differs from the original code.

If you really want to use a ternary operator, a work around would be:

```
hasDigit = isdigit(password[i]) ? 1 : hasDigit;
hasUpper = isupper(password[i]) ? 1 : hasUpper;
hasLower = islower(password[i]) ? 1 : hasLower;
```

but to me that code has a "smell" and I would prefer the version using if-statements.

The "lack" of `continue` also means that you do some unnecessary function calls which may have some performance impact but that's probably a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the ternary operator at all?

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)
{
    int c = password[i];
    hasDigit |= isdigit(c);
    hasUpper |= isupper(c);
    hasLower |= islower(c);
}
```